# Datatables: 'bAutoWidth: false' not working when 'sScrollY' is set

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am using datatables to reformat the already existing table/DOM after page load. I have defined the column widths in percentages in `thead`

```
  <table border="1" style="table-layout: fixed; word-wrap: break-word;"
                    id='myTable'>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>GroupName</th>
                            <th style='width: 60%;'>Grouped By </th>
                            <th style='width: 15%;'>Count</th>
                            <th style='width: 25%;'>Download</th> 
                        </th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>....</tbody>
 </table>
```

JQuery code looks like this.

```
oTable = jq("#myTable").dataTable(
     {
        "bSort" : false,
        "bLengthChange" : false,
        "bJQueryUI" : true,
        "bPaginate" : false,
        "sScrollY": "200px",
        "bAutoWidth": false // Disable the auto width calculation 
    }).rowGrouping(
    {
        bExpandableGrouping : true //group by first column
    });
```

Issue is - When `sScrolly` is set, datatables calculates width automatically and sets equal width for all columns which it shouldn't be doing as `bAutoWidth` is set to false. On disabling it, columns widths are appropriately set as per percentages.
Any suggestions on how to make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted question on datatables forum and got an answer/fix from author.
In case anybody stumbles upon here 
http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/19089/datatables-039bautowidth-false039-not-working-when-039sscrolly039-is-set#Item_1